# PhpStorm doesn't know the correct $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]

Tags: php, apache, phpstorm

I'm new to PhpStorm and trying to set up my first project (an existing one) in the IDE . I'm "upgrading" from Notepad++ so using an IDE of any type is new to me as well.

So I can open my project just fine, see all the files, etc. but the annoying thing is that when I run one of the existing, very simple files (5 lines of code) in the project, which contains a command like this: `require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/{{directory}}/{{filename}}');` 
the result in the Run panel of PhpStorm has this:
`Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/{{directory}}/{{filename}}' ...`
[image: the code window with the "run" button]

[image: The resulting error in the Run panel at the bottom of PHPStorm]
In other words, it doesn't seem to know what the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` for the project is.

I've looked at all of the project paths and I believe they are correct (they passed the PhpStorm http test) and I've even gone into the `Settings > Directories` settings and designated the directory that the file is contained within as a "Sources" directory.

In my searching for a solution there are several posts that indicate that PhpStorm is supposed to "just know" where the `$_SERVER` is, but clearly that's not true in my case.

In PhpStorm I've also set up the "connection" in `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Deployment` for my local Apache instance.  I've tried both the "Local or mounted folder" option and the "In place" option.

And finally, I've gone to `Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP` and added the directory as an Include Path.

Every time, I get the "Fatal error:..." message. No change whatsoever in the error messages.

I've scoured the docs and the web and found nothing to resolve this issue.

BTW, the page has run before (i.e. it's not new) and from within PhpStorm (2020.2), I can run the page in a browser just fine.  It's only the Run panel error that is bugging me.  I expect my IDE to tell me when things are wrong, but it's frustrating when they are "right" and the IDE thinks they are "wrong".

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please make and screenshots that illustrate the issue.

Comment: *"It's only the Run panel error that is bugging me."*. 1) If I'm getting you correctly, the "Run" panel is created when you are executing CLI script. In CLI environment PHP does not create and populate `$_SERVER` at all. 2) PhpStorm does NOT alter (set custom value) `$_SERVER`, at all.

Comment: 3) By default `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is resolved to the project root folder. You can change it at `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP --> Analysis tab`. It is for IDE only -- it will not affect the actual code execution.

Comment: I've posted the relevant screens. 1) The "Run" is not a separate script, I'm just executing the code in the Editor; 2) I get that PHPStorm doesn't alter the $_SERVER values, but I presume that it does "read" the $_SERVER values based on some setting; ...or 3) are you suggesting that I have to set the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in that Analysis tab?

Comment: 1) But you ARE running that as a CLI script -- the screenshot confirms that. Look at the selected Run/Debug Configuration and what type that is -- it will be "PHP Script" type. PHP does not set `$_SERVER` for CLI. You must have created that "PHP Script" configuration by mistake. Delete it and create one for more appropriate type. 3) If you need it for code analysis and DOCUMENT_ROOT is not your project root -- then Yes. if it's to get rid of that run time error -- then look at #1 again.

Comment: Run/Debug Configurations: 1) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/run-debug-configuration.html 2) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html 3) https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/run-debug-configurations-dialog.html